# GIT: Create branch only with certain files from master

Tags: git

I would like to create a branch that would contain only certain files from master. Let's say master contains several directories as follows:

```
app
app/test
app/dev
...
```

What I want to achieve is checking out contents of `app/test` into new branch and putting them into directory root, so it looks like this:

```
root
  - file from app/test
  - another file from app/test
  ...
```

Is this possible? In general what I want to do is pushing only some files (the new branch) to remote different from origin. This was the first idea I got, if there is simpler solution, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: And you want the history to be imported and preserved  till date ?

Comment: That is what I actually do not care about very much. I would appreciate if it was possible to do checkout everytime these files in master are changed.

Comment: Aah so its not a one time process ? You want these files to be imported into teh new branch everytime those files change in master ? Am I getting it right ?

Comment: Are you looking fro this ?                                                     # Suppose you are on master branch
git checkout hotfix1
git checkout master -- appl/login.php
git commit -m “Obtained the recent copy of login.php from master"

Comment: Yes, I want them imported everytime.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to create a new branch as usual, then prune its contents using [`git filter-branch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html).

Comment: git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter project-directory HEAD seems to do the trick, thank you very much!

Comment: It seemed to be working, but how do I update files from master again? When I run the command again I am given 'Found nothing to rewrite'.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this ?

```
# Suppose you #Suppose you are on master branch
git checkout hotfix1
git checkout master -- appl/login.php
git commit -m “Obtained the recent copy of login.php from master"
```

Comment: Generally yes, but I would like to put those files into root of directory.

Comment: You can mkdir the root, cd into it and run git checkout there. It should pull the files you intend to there itself.

Comment: I have a similar needs and I do not understand how to initiate the branch `hotfix1`. As far as I understand it should be initially empty, isn't it ? Or the second command is going to empty it keeping only the content of app1/login.php ?